# Multiple website translation for pure/static html webpage

Tags: html, translation

Imagine a pure/static html website. I mean no server side logic, just some html/css/js.

How would I provide such a website in multiple languages? Would it be satisfying to have have a directory for every language on the server? Like

```
website root 
    - en
       -index.htm
    - de
       -index.htm
    ...
```

Actually I do not see any problems using this approach. What do you think? May there be issues regarding SEO and google indexing this sites?

Comment: Some good info on this post I think: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/-9cw2oVpmOM

Comment: regarding SEO there wont be any issues if you intend to use the directory structure. 1 big disadvantage of doing it this way: maintaining and upkeep is going to be a lot of work.

Comment: It is a good idea to use templating engine, even for static web. You can keep code small and maintainable that way and retain most benefits of static website.